# PHP newbie error:: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

the Following line of code

```
 echo “<a href=’http: //localhost/moviesite.php?favmovie=Stripes' > ";
```

throws the error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
```

Any help on what Im doing wrong here would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: THIS was upvoted?! Why? Even the Stackoverflow highlighting reveals the problem.

Comment: But why downvoting too? This is a problem that can happen, I remember spending a lot of time on a similar stupid problem. So I think that can help others.

Comment: @jptsetung, I'm not saying this isn't worth asking, but it certainly is not worth upvoting.

Comment: @jptsetung: Note the title on the down arrow: "This question doesn't show any research effort"? Check. Twenty seconds with a search engine, and the OP would have their answer. Moreover, I consider dumping the code and the error message (without any obvious effort on the side of the asker) very rude: "here code, you debug."

Comment: Yeah I agree I upvoted only because it had been downvoted. I don't think it's fair to downvote this, no easy keywords, or if you have the good keywords you already know how to solve it.

Comment: I really dont understand why there is a downvote.. There are other similar questions,that have been left untouched or been upvoted ..:s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first double quote and single quote are incorrect, it should be `"` and `'`:

```
echo "<a href='http://localhost/moviesite.php?favmovie=Stripes'>";
```

On the other hand I think that this would be better (using `"` in HTML):

```
echo '<a href="http://localhost/moviesite.php?favmovie=Stripes">';
```

More info about [PHP strings & quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 2):

The first quotea are the wrong type:

`echo “<a href=’http: //localhost/moviesite.php?favmovie=Stripes' > ";`

Should be

`echo "<a href='http: //localhost/moviesite.php?favmovie=Stripes' > ";`

Answer (score 1):

Because **“** and **’** are not the right characters, replace them with **"** and **'**